# Archiving Sharepoint folders

Tags: 2010, folder, archive

We have a document library wish some SharePoint folders with some documents in them. We now need to archive these folders and their contents.

From what I am seeing, we cannot move the folder to another list through a workflow. We cannot declare the folder a record and move it to a records center.

What is the approach I should be taking here? (aside from open in explorer and move them that way)

Ideally, I would like to mark the folder as "completed" and once that happens, the folder and its contents move to an archive location.

Please help :)